# Laravel: set-cookie on EVERY request

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, csrf, setcookie

I'm using Laravel for a while but I have problem with one thing. Laravel sets cookie for every request. No matter user is logged in or not.

[image: set-cookie in laravel]

I don't think this is a normal behavior for Laravel. Once a user is logged in we don't need to create new session for them on every request. Do we? So why does laravel generate new session and csrf token for every request that user send? And also it generates these sessions and tokens for guest users too which is completely unnecessary and useless.

How can I prevent this?

### Update:

I use Laravel 5.2 and File as session driver.

Here are sample of my routes and middleware:

**Routes:**

```
<?php

Route::get('/login', 'UserController@login');
Route::post('/login', 'UserController@postLogin');
Route::get('/link/{link}', 'HomeController@link');


$router->group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::post('/', 'HomeController@postindex');

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::post('/home', 'HomeController@postindex');

    Route::get('user/{username}', 'UserController@user_info');
    Route::post('user/{username}', 'UserController@post_user_info');

    Route::get('/logout', 'UserController@logout');
});

$router->group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'role:2']], function() {
    Route::get('/tools/register', 'UserController@register');
    Route::post('/tools/register', 'UserController@postregister');

    Route::get('/tools/users', 'AdminController@users');
    Route::post('/tools/users', 'AdminController@post_users');
});


Route::controllers([
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

**Kernel.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'role' => \App\Http\Middleware\Role::class,
    ];
}
```

Comment: what version of laravel are you using?

Comment: @OliverQueen Laravel 5.2

Comment: I had to write my own middleware to fix this.

Comment: Can you show us your route and middleware settings?

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes. Updated the question

Comment: the value of `laravel_session` in the cookies in not the session ID, that can be seen dumping `Session::all();` on a page: `_token` should be the same

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked but your route is probably in the default "Web" middleware group that has sessions/cookies/csrf by default.

[Laravel Middlewares](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware)

Comment: My site uses sessions/cookie/csrf. But setting these cookies and sessions on every request, again and again is weird

Comment: @Sky Is it setting *new* IDs with every request? The `Set-Cookie` calls should be there on every request, but the session ID should be staying constant.

Comment: @ceejayoz Both session and csrf, change on every request and they are not constant.

Comment: what is your laravel session driver?

Comment: @MarijanSpasenovski The default one. File

Comment: Can you try switching to database driver and see if anything changes?

Comment: @MarijanSpasenovski Same behavior unfortunately. Both session and csrf exist and keep changing